# Trace of two equal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix and it is Involuntary matrix means $A= A^{-1}$. Then it is always true that $trace (A)= trace (A^{-1})$?

Comment: If $A=B$ then $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\mathrm{tr}(B)$... It's a tautology. Did you mean $\mathrm{tr}(A^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(A)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: "Involuntary" matrix...?

Comment: @DonAntonio I think that's [this Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two matrices are equal, that means they literally have the same entries.  The trace of a matrix is the sum of its diagonal entries, so if two matrices are equal they have the same trace: you're adding up the exact same numbers.